# Using GHCi to load a module without access to its source code

Tags: haskell, ghci, hint

I create a simple module, `TestModule.hs`, which contains a single exported top-level definition `testval = 2`. I compile it, creating `TestModule.o` and `TestModule.hi`. I **delete** `TestModule.hs`. I then load `TestModule.o` in `ghci`, like this:

```
~ λ ghci TestModule.o
GHCi, version 7.0.3.20110517: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading object (static) TestModule.o ... done
final link ... done
Prelude>
```

As you can see, `TestModule` isn't in scope and I cannot access `testval`. Why? How can I accomplish this without access to the source file?

Additional question: how do I accomplish the same thing using the `hint` package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't interpret something that's already been compiled. If you want to interpret it, you need the source. You can make a package, if you like. Instructions are [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program).

Comment: That's true if interpretation happens from source. But most modern "interpreters" interpret from an intermediate representation, such as bytecode. I think I read GHCi does that too, and I don't see a reason it shouldn't. Do you have a source that says otherwise?

Comment: Using the GHC API, I can get the value behind an exported top-level definition using just the .o and .hi file (with the .hs file deleted). So, getting this value seems to me as completely possible. I just need to figure out how to do the same thing using ghci or hint.